# Setting a local variable that keeps its value across multiple calls in a shell function

Tags: bash

I'm looking for the best solution. I want use in function only local variable, so global variable declared before call function is ignored.

Example:

```
username="niquit"

User() {
local parsedoptions=$( getopt -q -n "$0" -o u: -- "$@" )
eval set -- "$parsedoptions"

while :
do
    case "$1" in
    -u)
        if [[ $2 ]]
        then
            local username=$2
        fi

        shift 2;;
    --)
        shift

        break;;
    esac
done

if [[ $username ]]
then
    echo "Error"
else
    local username="test"
fi
}

 User -u test
```

I can of course use change the variable name in function for `User_username` or unset all knotted local variable at begin of function but I want skip these solutions.

Comment: What meaning is the `$username` at the top of the function supposed to have? Local functions are deleted when they leave scope, so if you expect it to be the version set when `User` was last called, that won't ever happen (not just in bash, but in *most* languages).

Comment: BTW, see [obsolete and deprecated syntax](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete) re: the `function` keyword. Right now you're using a mix of POSIX-compliant and ksh-compatible syntax that is neither POSIX-compliant *nor* ksh-compatible.

Comment: (also, the ksh version of the syntax doesn't actually provide any of its benefits when used in bash -- on ksh, `function User {` would create a function where all newly-defined variables are local by default, but on bash, the `function` keyword has no semantic benefits whatsoever over the POSIX-compliant alternative).

Comment: BTW, editing your question in such a way as to turn it into a completely different question *after it was given an answer that was correct per the manner in which it was initially asked* is frowned on somewhat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Emulating Static Variables Using Namevars

Regular function-scoped local variables do not retain their values across multiple calls to a function in any widely-used programming language (if this property existed by default, it would be much harder to write reentrant code -- that is, functions that are safe to use recursively). In languages that have them, variables that have this behavior are called "static variables".

Bash does not natively support static variables.

As a workaround, consider a global variable naming convention that includes your function name -- combined with a namevar to let you refer to these globals by your desired, shorter, local name:

```
User() {
  declare -g User__username
  local -n username=User__username  ## NOTE: THIS REQUIRES BASH 4.3 OR NEWER

  if [[ $username ]]; then
    echo "OK: Already set to $username"
  else
    username=test
  fi

  echo "$username"
}
```

---

#### Original Question: On Local Variables

Local variables aren't local until they're *declared* local. You need to put that declaration at the top of your function:

```
User() {
    local username
    if [[ $username ]]; then
      echo "FAILED: Non-local variables should never be visible"
    else
      username="test"
    fi
    echo "$username"
}
```

`local var=whatever` is bad practice for other reasons as well: If you run `var=$(something)`, the exit status will reflect whether `something` succeeded, but if you run `local var=$(something)`, then it reflects whether `local` succeeded, discarding the exit status of `something`.

Comment: How can the `if [[ $username ]]` ever succeed after the `local username`?

Comment: @choroba, it won't, but that appears to be what the OP wants. I tried to express that to them in the very first comment on the question.

Comment: Maybe they rather want `local username=$username` (or the longer version of the same)?

Comment: Okay, I changed example. Maybe it will now more understandable.

Comment: I'd use `User__username` (function name, two underscores, variable name) convention in this case. What you want is what other languages call a "static" variable, not a "local" variable, and bash doesn't have them at all.

Comment: This is reason of my question, I was looking internet for any solution without changing the variable name or declared variable name at begin of function.

Comment: There is no such feature. Not part of the language, not available, can't do it, etc.